# GmapPanel add marker on click - EXTJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, extjs, extjs4

```
function addDoctorLocation(lat,longt) 
    {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(longt));
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
     //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          title:"Hello World!"
      });

      // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
      var map = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
      marker.setMap(map); 
    }

var btn= Ext.getCmp('button');
btn.on('onclick', function(){
            addDoctorLocation(3.951941,102.052002);
    })
```

mygooglemap is a GMappanel
how to click the button and then gmappanel will add a marker with coordinate `3.951941,102.052002`?
i have tried this code,but still can't work?

### UPDATE

how about on check box?

```
tree.on('checkchange', function(node){
  var data = node.data;
  if (data.checked = true){
     var options = {
       lat:3.951941,
       lng:-102.052002,
       marker: {title:"Hello World!"},
       listeners: {
         click: function(e){
         }
       }     
     }
     addDoctorLocation(options);
  }     
})
```

### MAP CREATION

```
var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            //renderTo: 'layout',
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                title: 'Message List',
                region: 'south',     // position for region
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 100,
                split: true,         // enable resizing
                collapsible: true,
                margins: '0 5 5 5',
                collapsed: true
            },tree,{
                    xtype: 'gmappanel',
                    id : 'mygooglemap',
                    gmapType: 'map',
                    zoomLevel: 7,
                    mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
                    mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],  
                    setCenter: {
                        lat: 3.951941,
                        lng: 102.052002,
                    }
                }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
        });
    });
```

after i checked fireBug the error are:

```
ReferenceError: GLatLng is not defined
[Break On This Error]   
var mpoint = new GLatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
```

i have edited the code as below,work fine

```
function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{
 var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
 var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
 gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
}
```

Comment: Nice. You should be using v3, do you ?

Comment: Gmappanel3.js? what do u mean? @Ankit

Comment: do you how to handle click on map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var btn= Ext.getCmp('button');
btn.on('onclick', function(){
  var options = {
    lat:3.951941,
    lng:-102.052002,
    marker: {title:"Hello World!"},
    listeners: {
     click: function(e){

     }
    }                
   }     
   addDoctorLocation(options);
})

function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{

 var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
 var mpoint = new GLatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
 gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
}
```

Note:- This code is to just add a marker other than center point. At this point you should have your map created with 'id:mygooglemap'. Looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to create a new map than to add a marker on existing map.

You can always refer GMapPanel.js file for addMarker function which comes with extjs package. I have old version so addMarker call is accordingly.

Comment: what is the listeners value? and how to get it?

Comment: if inside checkbox ? `click: function(e){` change this to? i hav eupdated my code,please see above

Comment: You missed one of the closing bracket in tree code so addDoctorLocation call is out side if statement. I modified it in your code, try it and let me know. Did you read note in my answer. You should have map created at the time of adding the marker. Please also refer addMarker method in GMapPanel.js.